# How to use a package of generated protobuf inside a go module?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, go-modules, protoc

I encounter an issue with Go Module management and a generation of protobuffers (using go1.16, protoc-gen-go@latest).

I have this project structure:

```
subproj
├── go.mod         (module company.tld/proj/subproj)
├── subproj.go     (entry point : package main)
├── proto          (folder containing .proto files)
├── packageFolder
|   └── file1.go   (package packageFolder)
└── Makefile       (used to generate *.pb.go and build subproj binary)
```

The *proto* folder is used by other projects (obviously...) (via git submodule).
Protos are like the following:

```proto
syntax = "proto3"
option csharp_namespace = "Proj.Proto";
option go_package = "company.tld/proj/projpb";
package entity.proj
...
```

because of different version of messages, few protobuffer files need to be in another "namespace":

```proto
option go_package = "company.tld/proj/projpb/other";
package entity.proj.other
```

In my Makefile, I tried to generate the right *.pb.go at the right place:

```
# Proto sources
PROTO= $(wildcard ${PROTODIR}/*.proto)
PBGO=  $(PROTO:.proto=.pb.go)

MODULE_NAME=company.tld/proj
GO_OPT_FLAG=   --go_opt=module=${MODULE_NAME}     
GRPC_OPT_FLAG= --go-grpc_opt=module=${MODULE_NAME}
#GO_OPT_FLAG=   --go_opt=paths=import
#GRPC_OPT_FLAG= --go-grpc_opt=paths=import

.PHONY: clean install proto

## Builds the project
build: proto
    go build ${LDFLAGS} -o ${BINARY}

$(PROTOBUF_GO_PLUGIN):
    go install google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go@latest

$(GRPC_GO_PLUGIN):
    go install google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc@latest

%.pb.go: %.proto | $(PROTOBUF_GO_PLUGIN) $(GRPC_GO_PLUGIN)
    protoc --proto_path=${PROTODIR} --go_out=. ${GO_OPT_FLAG} --go-grpc_out=. ${GRPC_OPT_FLAG} $<

proto: $(PBGO)
```

So, depending on the option used with the protoc compiler:
→ With `--go_opt=paths=import`

A folder tree *company.tld/proj/projpb* is created by protoc at the project's root. Each object is in a package called *projpb* or *other*, in the subpackage other.

Generated Proto objects, that include the *other* namespace-d objects, have the import path `import other "company.tld/proj/projpb/other"` (which is brought by the `go_package` option, but which is wrong because it is not an existing module - go mod tidy/vendor is complaining that it cannot find it).

Normal project files need the following import path to reach the Generated Proto objects :
`import pb "company.tld/proj/subproj/company.tld/proj/projpb"`
which seems odd and not the proper way to do.

→ With `--go_opt=module=company.tld/proj`

A folder *projpb* is created by protoc at the project's root and each generated .pb.go has the package *projpb* or *other*, in the subpackage other.

Generated Proto objects, that include the *other* namespace-d objects, still have the import path `import other "company.tld/proj/projpb/other"` (which is still brought by the `go_package` option and is still wrong because this is still a non-existing module - these are generated files... why would I want to create a module of these ?).

The cool thing is that with this go_opt, accessing generated types looks much more normal with
`import pb "company.tld/proj/subproj/projpb"`.

Finally, I tried

- using local import path on the go_package option in the .proto files (that is refused on build time, because there would be an `import other "./projpb/other"` in generated protobuffer object)
- to use the *replace* instruction in the go.mod file like this :

```
replace (
    company.tld/proj/projpb => ./projpb
    company.tld/proj/projpb/other => ./projpb/other
)
```

(but go mod tidy/vendor is complaining that it cannot find the go.mod file inside the generated folder ./projpb)

Has someone encountered a similar problem? Or am I missing a command option to tell to Go, «I generate protobuffer objects in a package, or package in a package, and I simply want to use them. They are not a module, so please, provide the right import paths to the generated object and let me use them in my code».

---

[Update 01]
I gave a try to the `go_opt=paths=source_relative` (inspired by this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62540631/7135482)).
I created the folder in the Makefile, protoc generates files inside.
Notes:

- generated protos use the full path, specified with the `go_package` option, to relate to one another.
- As long as `go_package` option needs a full path, Go (go mod tidy/vendor) will want to search for a go.mod file inside the created folder, containing generated protos.

What is the correct way to tell Go that I am not looking for a Module, yet still satisfy the go_package option's full path constraint in the protobuffer file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After changing a numerous amount of time the `go_package` option in the proto files, changing the `go_opt` on the protoc compiler command, the only way I found to compile my project with my generated protobuffers, respecting every Go constraints, is **by creating a go.mod file on-the-fly**...

final proto «header»  (respects the full puth in the `go_package` option)

```proto
syntax = "proto3";
option csharp_namespace = "Proj.Proto";
option go_package = "company.tld/proj/projpb";
// or for subpackages...
option csharp_namespace = "Proj.Proto.Other";
option go_package = "company.tld/proj/projpb/other";
```

my Makefile  (creates a go.mod file for the generated proto files)

```
# Proto sources
PROTO= $(shell find ${PROTODIR} -type f -name '*.proto')
PBGO=  $(PROTO:.proto=.pb.go)

DEST_DIR=.
MODULE_NAME=company.tld/proj
GO_OPT_FLAG=   --go_opt=module=${MODULE_NAME}
GRPC_OPT_FLAG= --go-grpc_opt=module=${MODULE_NAME}

PROTO_PKG_DIR=projpb
PROTO_MODULE_NAME=${MODULE_NAME}/${PROTO_PKG_DIR}
PROTO_GOMOD_FILE=${PROTO_PKG_DIR}/go.mod

.PHONY: clean install proto gomod

build: proto gomod
    go build ${LDFLAGS} -o ${BINARY}

%.pb.go: %.proto | $(PROTOBUF_GO_PLUGIN) $(GRPC_GO_PLUGIN) $(DEST_DIR)
    ${PROTOC} --proto_path=${PROTODIR} --go_out=${DEST_DIR} ${GO_OPT_FLAG} --go-grpc_out=${DEST_DIR} ${GRPC_OPT_FLAG} $<

proto: $(PBGO)

gomod: ${PROTO_GOMOD_FILE}

${PROTO_GOMOD_FILE}:
    cd ${PROTO_PKG_DIR} && go mod init ${PROTO_MODULE_NAME} && cd ..
```

my main go.mod file  (redirects the on-the-fly-created module to a local folder inside the project's scope)

```
module company.tld/proj/subproj

go 1.16

require (
    // ...
    company.tld/proj/projpb v0.0.0
)

replace company.tld/proj/projpb v0.0.0 => ./projpb
```

Thanks to the `replace` instruction, go mod tidy/vendor is happy and do not try to search the module in a remote repository.
Generated *.pb.go files have the right import path : `company.tld/proj/projpb` (and `company.tld/proj/projpb/other` for the subpackages).
And the import statement to use generated protos are working fine in the main project.

I hoped there was a simpler and more prettier solution, but alas...

Sorry for the any and thanks to those who gave it a thought !

Comment: The simpler and prettier solution is given in https://blog.golang.org/generate: “[I]f the containing package is intended for import by `go get`, once the file is generated (and tested!) it must be checked into the source code repository to be available to clients.” So the more scalable solution here is to either publish an actual `company.tld/proj/projpb` containing the generated code, or change the generated import paths to be within the `company.tld/proj/subproj` module and commit the generated code there.

Comment: @bcmills thanks for your comment ! Your point is interesting, but it forces me to push the generated files in the repositories that use the proto files, (if I understood well...). Each time a proto is changed, the team would have to circle on each project and make a commit "Update generated proto classes", which is not really convenient. From my point of view, if I wasn't force to use a full import path in the `go_package` option, I could generate and use the files as coming from a local package (without entering the complexity of Go Modules).

Comment: If I recall correctly, the `github.com/golang/protobuf/proto` API requires the existence of only one package per proto file. To me, that implies the existence of a single module _somewhere_ — probably the one containing the `.pb.go` files — that provides the canonical generated code for that version of the `.proto` files. So each time the `.proto` file is changed, whoever is committing the change to that file would also need to regenerate and commit the `.pb.go` files as well.

Comment: oh sorry ! By «the team would have to circle on each project», I was meaning on projects using different languages (Go, C++, C#, NodeJS, so far...), but sharing the same protobuffers. So, yes, you're right on saying that the API requires only one package per proto file, and that would be a fair solution if we had only Go projects. In my case, proto are regenerated before the build of each project (Go, C++...) automatically, avoiding the creation of a "module"-equivalence, containing the generated files, per language. We only need to point the right commit in the proto repo/git-submodule.