# Can't generate grpc files for go

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

There is a directory

```
├── cmd
│   └── main.go
├── go.mod
└── proto
    └── forward.proto
```

write in the terminal

```
protoc --go_out=. --go_opt=paths=source_relative \
    --go-grpc_out=. --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative \
    proto/forward.proto
```

I get the error

> protoc-gen-go: invalid Go import path "forward" for
> "proto/forward.proto"
>
> The import path must contain at least one forward slash ('/')
> character.
>
> See
> https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/go-generated#package
> for more information.
>
> --go_out: protoc-gen-go: Plugin failed with status code 1. a.mamedov@a-mamedov forward-spinner %

How to fix it and generate grpc for forward.proto file?

Comment: Please check this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61666805/correct-format-of-protoc-go-package) that describes `go_option` you can use to generate proto code.

Comment: the error msg shows the error, please post your proto file, especially the import and option part

Comment: btw, this may help https://github.com/techschool/pcbook-go/issues/3#issuecomment-821860413

Comment: Please show us your first lines of the proto file.

Answer (score 10):

The problem lies on the `.proto` file, in line `option go_package="forward";`.

In order to compile the code just add `./` in front of the require file:

`option go_package="./forward";`