# protoc-gen-go: unable to determine Go import path for "simple.proto"

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, protoc

I have simple proto file with following content.

```
syntax="proto3";

package main;

message Person {
      string name = 1;
      int32 age = 2; 
}
```

I am trying to generate go code for it using protoc. I run:

```
protoc --go_out=. simple.proto
```

I receive following error:

```
protoc-gen-go: unable to determine Go import path for "simple.proto"

Please specify either:
        • a "go_package" option in the .proto source file, or
        • a "M" argument on the command line.
```

`main.go`, `go.mod` and `simple.proto` is in the same folder. Both `protoc` and `protoc-gen-go` are defined in PATH enviroement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct format of protoc go\_package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61666805/correct-format-of-protoc-go-package)

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68969208/2270041

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are missing `option go_package.`

The name you will give to `option go_package` will be the name of the package that will be generated by the protoc. By doing so, you can import thus access message fields.

Answer (score 24):

Protoc requires that the package be specified, then the solution is to add

```proto
option go_package = "./your-package-name";
```

to make your file looks like the following:

```proto
syntax="proto3";

package main;

option go_package = "./your-package-name";

message Person {
      string name = 1;
      int32 age = 2; 
}
```

then you can run the command e.g:

```sh
protoc -I src/ --go_out=src/ src/simple/simple.proto
```

where `--go_out=src/` specifies where your file will be generated then the relative path to your proto file.

**Note:** Don't forget to prefix the `option go_package` with `./`

Comment: Commenting cause edit queue is full. PLEASE ADD a ";" at the end like:  option go_package = "./your-package-name";

Answer (score 17):

You forgot to linkedlist the file with it by adding:

```
option go_package = "./";
```

You need to linkedlist it first to make it work. It was same [issues here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61666805/correct-format-of-protoc-go-package)

Comment: if .proto is on root then this will work nice +1

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem.

I thought protocol buffers were supposed to be language neutral. If we are adding go_package to the proto files, then if we try to compile these proto files to a different language, we will have to make changes to the files.

The solutions I have seen works if you are looking at generating only go files.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your first answer! I think this probably fits better as a comment to the question than an answer, because you don't actually give a solution. You can add comments to questions just below the question itself.

Answer (score -3):

first make sure you installed compiler correctly

```
sudo apt install protobuf-compiler
sudo apt install golang-goprotobuf-dev
```

use this command

```
protoc -I=src/ --go_out=src/ src/simple.proto
```

-I = IPATH -Specify the directory in which to search for imports 
--go_out=  output directory

Comment: Why src and simple subdirectories?

Comment: subdirectory  will not cause any problem

Comment: Question clearly states every file is in same folder. Pointing out folder doesn't exist will create an error