# Solving protoc-gen-go: unable to determine Go import path problem by adding a "M" argument

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, protoc, grpc-go

Same symptom as [protoc-gen-go: unable to determine Go import path for "simple.proto"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70586511/protoc-gen-go-unable-to-determine-go-import-path-for-simple-proto)

> For simple proto file with following content.
>
> ```
> syntax="proto3";
>
> package main;
>
> message Person {
>       string name = 1;
>       int32 age = 2; 
> }
> ```
>
> I am trying to generate go code for it using protoc. I run:
>
> ```
> protoc --go_out=. --go_opt=paths=source_relative --go-grpc_out=. --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative simple.proto
> ```
>
> I receive following error:
>
> ```
> protoc-gen-go: unable to determine Go import path for "simple.proto"
>
> Please specify either:
>         • a "go_package" option in the .proto source file, or
>         • a "M" argument on the command line.
> ```

All the answer there focus on the *first* option -- adding `a "go_package" option in the .proto source file`, but I'm looking for the answer for the *second* option *"**a "M" argument** on the command line"*.

Same as the comments under https://stackoverflow.com/a/62540631/2125837

I'm looking for ways to change the module path *via `protoc`*, to generate Go code for both a client and server that are part of *different* modules, I tried using `go_opt=module` but it doesn't work with `source_relative`.

Is there any ways to make it work by adding *"a "M" argument on the command line"*, instead of adding a "`go_package`" option in the .proto source file please?

Specifically, for the file of
https://github.com/mmcc007/go/blob/master/examples/helloworld/helloworld/helloworld.proto

Here are my failed attempts:

```
$ protoc --go_out=. --go_opt=paths=source_relative --go-grpc_out=. --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative --proto_path=examples/helloworld/helloworld helloworld.proto 

protoc-gen-go: unable to determine Go import path for "helloworld.proto"
. . .
--go_out: protoc-gen-go: Plugin failed with status code 1.


$ protoc --go_out=. --go_opt=paths=source_relative --go-grpc_out=. --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative --proto_path=examples/helloworld/helloworld --go_opt=Mhelloworld.proto=github.com/mmcc007/go/blob/master/examples/helloworld/helloworld helloworld.proto 

protoc-gen-go-grpc: unable to determine Go import path for "helloworld.proto"
. . .
--go_out: protoc-gen-go: Plugin failed with status code 1.
```

Comment: Please can you clarify the sentence "*to generate Go code for both a client and server that are part of different modules*". Do you want to have a module for the client and a module for the server or do you want to compile different files to different import paths? Note that `protoc` doesn't care about *modules*, it only generates Go code. How you distribute that code is up to you

Comment: Can I ask what's the purpose ? Why not having a separate module for your protos and specify a `go_package`?

Comment: @ClémentJean / @blackgreen, put it is way, if I put `go_package` in the .proto source file, then it'll tie to a specific repo. But for such sample repo, if people to fork it elsewhere, it'll be more convenient to set the import path on cli for protoc, instead of hard-coding it. But regardless for any reason, if the 2nd option is available, I want to know how to make use of it.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/go-generated#package provides an example using the `-M` option

Comment: @menghanl, yep, that url is part of the error output. If you take a look at the 2nd command in my OP, you can see that I'm following the example using the -M option from the official doc, yet, still getting that _"unable to determine Go import path"_ error.

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: looked through the code, but it is also in the documentation @xpt linked. You only have to find the  ; (semicolon) giving you control over the package name (go and go-grpc do not produce the same package name)  ::example:: `protoc --go-grpc_out=fizz --go-grpc_opt="Mprotopath/buzz.proto=example.com/project/internal/proto;bar,module=example.com/project" protopath/buzz.proto` generates `fizz/internal/proto/buzz_grpc.pb.go`  with `package bar` (i know it is not sensible, only example) ref: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf-go/blob/v1.31.0/compiler/protogen/protogen.go#L499C31-L499C44

Comment: one of the worst command line tools I have used recently..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found this to be working using `--proto_path` for easy reference using "THE M FLAG" :-)

```
protoc --proto_path=./proto \
  --go_out=./go \
  --go_opt=Mhelloworld.proto=example.com/project/protos/fizz \
  ./proto/helloworld.proto
```

Note: The M before helloworld.proto

Comment: I find it very disappointing that your answer is the only source of info I've found that has finally helped me achieve the simple task of choosing where do I want the generated go code to go. The docs are un-findable, and the comments around the web do not really address this simple task.

Thank you @Chris G.

Comment: you could check it from this documentation https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/go-generated#package

Comment: fwiw.- I agree with @pablete - that blurb in the docs doesn't actually explain whether to use relative path or absolute path in the PROTO_FILE or the GO_IMPORT_PATH - also - the GO_IMPORT_PATH seems to be a weird combination of both namespace and file path.  I was never able to get the "-go_opt=M" command line arg to work - and just resorted to dumping the "option go_package = ..." into my .proto files.  I had used these same proto files to generate one language - but couldn't get them to work for golang.

Comment: In my case M option doesn't work .... it's ok with option go_package but it's doesn't see --go_opt=M... Have no idea why it happening

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the path in the command or in the proto file

```
syntax = "proto3";

option go_package = "pkg/api";
```

this is the same for java, and python as well.

```
option java_package = "pkg/api";
option py_generic_services = "pkg/api";
```

As for the command

Makefile

```
PROJ_PATH=${CURDIR}

.PHONY: proto
proto: ## Generate protobuf code
# Compile proto files inside the project.
    protoc api.proto --proto_path=${PROJ_PATH}/proto --go_out=. --go-grpc_out=.
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, after several hours of struggling I found that the **M** argument only worked when adding it both as `go_opt` and `go-grpc_opt`. E.g. for a proto file located in `proto/src/another/folder/helloworld.proto`:

```
protoc --proto_path=proto/src \
  --go_out=. \
  --go-grpc_out=. \
  --go_opt=Manother/folder/helloworld.proto=example.com/project/protos/fizz \
  --go-grpc_opt=Manother/folder/helloworld.proto=example.com/project/protos/fizz \
  proto/src/another/folder/helloworld.proto
```

In this case the file is located in `proto/src/another/folder/helloworld.proto`

Comment: Thanks for the input. It might well be the case ***now***.